# 1. Given a Turing Machine T , are there any input strings on which T loops forever? 2. Given a Turing Machine T and a string w, does T reject input w?

Tags: turing-machines, decidability

1. Given a Turing Machine T , are there any input strings on which T loops forever?
2. Given a Turing Machine T and a string w, does T reject input w?

How to prove the above two question's decidabiltiy , I understand these are undecidable but can someone help me prove that they are undecidable with the concepts of reducability.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh thank you for the suggestion , i'm new to the MSE , will rectify it from next posts , by the way could you help me with the question

Comment: Usually, the approach is to show that solving the given problem would allow to solve the halting problem which is known to be impossible.